# Why this equation is able to be said as the condition for composing a constant function?

Tags: systems-of-equations, mobius-transformation, constants

$a,b,c,d:=$non zero real number constants.

$t\geq0$

$f(t):=\frac{a+bt}{c+dt}$

The thing which I want to do is determine the values of the above $4$ constants to make $f(t)$ as a constant function.

The textbook gave the condition for it as below.

$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d}$

Why this equation is able to be said as the condition for composing a constant function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $t=0$ and $t=1$, we obtain that $\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$ is a necessary condition. Conversely, if $a = \frac{bc}{d}$ then $\frac{bc/d + bt}{c+dt} = \frac{b}{d}$, a constant.

Answer (score 0):

We want $ f(t) = \frac{a + bt}{c + dt} = e$, where $e$ is some constant

This should hold for all values of t. So taking $t = 0$

$ \frac{a}{c} = e \Rightarrow a = ec$

If $t = 1$:

$\frac{a+b}{c+d} = e \Rightarrow a + b = (c + d)e = ec + ed = a + ed$

$\Rightarrow b = ed \Rightarrow e = \frac{b}{d}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$